# How to set simple form alignment style in web2py?

Tags: python, forms, web, web2py

I am using simple form in web2py. In controller I create a form like this:

```
form=FORM(DIV(INPUT(_id='itemId',_name='itemId',_value='102737069',requires=[IS_NOT_EMPTY("please input correct itemId"),IS_LENGTH(maxsize=12)]), INPUT(_type='submit',_value='search_key',_name='search'), INPUT(_type='submit',_value="random_key",_name='random')))
```

In corresponding html the form is embedded in a `div` tag and I want the form align to center. How to set it？ Thanks.

**EDIT:**
This is the html code. Now I can only use two 
 to align the form to center approximately.
I am new in css.

```
<div class="top">
<div class="header_left">
      <div class="msg">
         please submit the itemId...
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="header_right">
<br/><br/>
{{=form}}
</div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

Comment: Could you also post the respective html along with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning `div` tag that the form is in, add `align="center"`.

So if I'm understanding your issue correctly then you'll want to put `align="center"` in the    `<div class="header_right">` like found in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6YyW/).